# Не знаю куда поместить поле в БД

Tags: sql, база-данных

Есть база даных школы языков. Есть такие таблицы:

```
Level 
Language 
Teacher 
Cabinet 
Course 
Student
```

Поле `cost(обозначает стоимость курса)` храниться в таблице `Course(курс)` а куда поместить поле `Paid(обозначает сколько денег оплачено за курс)`
Если я правильно понимаю, то в таблицу `Student`, но откуда тогда знать за что именно заплатил деньги студент ? Нужно ли тогда добавить в `Student` еще и поле `Course_id`, чтобы знать за что заплатил студент?

Comment: Встречный вам вопрос: а как вы узнаете какой учитель, в каком кабинете, какой курс, каким студентам преподаёт? Без структуры таблиц (по крайней мере относящихся к вопросу) вопрос не решить

Comment: Для отплат нужна отдельная таблица, где будет id-студента и id-курса, уплаченная сумма (мне кажется он может частями платить), возможно дата оплаты

Comment: Тарас, @Mike тебе дает верное направление

Comment: Если вы добавите в таблицу `Student` поле `Course_id`, каждый студент сможет взять только один курс...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Минимально приемлемый результат - дополнительная таблица `payment`, где будут поля `student_id`, `course_id` и, скорее всего, `payment_date`. Минимально приемлемый - потому что так вы сможете отмечать только факты оплаты, а еще возможны скидки (всякие "три курса по цене двух"), оплата по частям и т. д. Для всего этого может понадобиться довольно много таблиц.